# Как копировать базу из MS SQL 2008 в MS SQL Compact CE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Вопрос в следующем - в ms sql 2008 есть база данных с определенными таблицами, необходимо переместить эти таблицы в ms compact ce (3.5), желательно "программным" методом, приложение на C#. Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1):

Можно через скрипт: http://erikej.blogspot.ru/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html
Можно утилитой: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25685/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database

Comment: ms sql 2008 не поддерживается судя по описанию

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться незаслуженно забытым [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/ru/ru/sync-framework.aspx)

Нужно скачать SDK и после можно будет добавить в проект Visual Studio Local Database Cache. Для него потребуется проекта для клиента и сервера. Общаться они будут через веб-сервис. Всё настраиваться через визарды и есть примеры, но к сожалению на английском, например: http://www.codemag.com/article/0712092